# Where can I find the data for secular bull and bear markets?

Tags: data-request, economics

I'm interested in doing some analysis on the [Secular Bull and Bear Markets](http://www.advisorperspectives.com/dshort/updates/Secular-Bull-and-Bear-Markets) graph as found on this page. Ideally I would like daily data, but end of year data would be fine.

The article also mentions "adjustments". I was wondering what type of adjustments were done and what were they for.